# How to use XMLRPC Client ServerProxy with SSL

Tags: python-3.x, ssl

According to [the official doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xmlrpc.client.html#xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy):

```
class xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(uri, transport=None, encoding=None, verbose=False, allow_none=False, use_datetime=False, use_builtin_types=False, *, context=None)
```

I am currently stuck in that asterisk `*` parameter.

My work:

```
import ssl
import xmlrpc

[...]
context = ssl.SSLContext()
proxy = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy("https://example.com/api", None, None, False, False, False, False, *, context)
```

The IDE throws a **unexpected arguments** error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution:

```
import ssl
import xmlrpc

[...]
context = ssl.SSLContext()
proxy = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy("https://example.com/api", context=context)
```

Comment: Could you share the server side code as well, if you're using python and xmlrpc for that also?